# How to pass function result to template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm working on django projects and I have a problem :
I would like to pass the results of function to a dynamic template.

```
def liste_ebauche(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() and not request.method == 'GET':
            raise Http404
    try:

            param_json = None
            param = request.GET 

            for json_liste_eb in param:
                    param_json= json.loads(json_liste_eb)

            of_select= param_json['numof'] 

            reponse= {}
            reponse_json= {}
            reb={}
            c=connection.cursor()
            c.execute("BEGIN")
            c.callproc("p_web_get_ebauche",[of_select])
            ebauches=c.fetchall()
            c.execute("COMMIT")
            c.close()

             html = render_to_string("paquet/ss_ebauche.html", locals())
    except Exception as e:
            logger.warning("error :" + e.message)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In my templates i' m doing :

```
{% for ebauche in ebauches %}
        <tr style="text-align:center">
                <td class="id_ss_ebauche" style="display:none;">{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td class="case">{{ebauche.ebauche}}</td>
                <td class="case">{{ebauche.type}}</td>
                <td class="case">{{ebauche.longueur}}</td>
                <td class="case">{{ebauche.ligne}}</td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It's ok if I transmit a queryset but not with results function.
How can I adapt result function to transmit to my template?
Please help me.

Comment: some_variable = my_func() (my_func() returns some result)

Comment: my function p_web_get_ebauche return a correct table, but how i format the result "ebauches" to pass to my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown what the contents of the `ebauches` variable are. You can check by printing or logging it after `ebauches=c.fetchall()` in the view.

If it's a list of tuples, then you would have to convert the result to a dictionary, or change your template to access the variables by index:

```
{% for ebauche in ebauches %}{{ ebauche.0 }}, {{ ebauche.1 }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [(u'123',u'a',u'E_ONE',u'0',NONE),(u'124',u'b',u'E_TWO',u'0',NONE)]

Comment: That's a list imof tuples as I predicted. You need to use index lookups as I suggested, or convert the tuples to dictionaries (how to do this can depend on which db you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'have find my problem. It's an ajax request,  reponse 'view  can't be a html link. The reponse pass by the function success of my request ajax.